# Sklearn: ValueError:Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [500, 1]

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am solving a machine learning problem using python's sklearn library

I am using pandas dataframe and i wanted to train a linear regression model using my local data and predict new values. here are my code samples.

```
customers= pd.read_csv('Ecommerce Customers')
X= customers[['Avg. Session Length', 'Time on App','Time on Website', 'Length of Membership']]
y=['Yearly Amount Spent']
```

when i try to run this below code

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=101)
```

it gives me an error

```
Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [500, 1]
```

in my dataset it has 500 rows and 8 columns
sklearn verion is

```
import sklearn
format(sklearn.__version__)
'0.20.1'
```

pls help me .
Thanks In advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking closely at your code, you don't take `y` to be a *column* of your dataframe `customers`, as you probably intend to do; as you have it

```
y=['Yearly Amount Spent']
```

`y` is just a 1-element list:

```
y
# ['Yearly Amount Spent']
```

hence scikit-learn justifiably complains that the length of your labels `y` is just 1.

Change it to

```
y=customers['Yearly Amount Spent']
```